# How to count number of DB table rows where column B value is "x" for the first occurrence of column A values in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm pretty new to Laravel. I have a projects table in `MySQL DB` represented by a model `Project.php` . I want to count rows based on two different column values. Each client can have multiple projects, and the status may be `ongoing` or `completed`. Let's say the `client_id column (Column A)` and the `status column (Column B)` are the two columns I want to base my counting upon.

I want to be able to count only the first row (if multiple exists) of the MySQL table where a particular client have `column B` value as `ongoing` as well as all other clients with `column B` values as `ongoing`. The image below depicts what the table looks like:

[image]

In this case, `client_id`s 1 and 3 have two `ongoing` projects each, I want to be able to count them as 1 each along with others (`client_id 2`). So the count for clients with `ongoing` projects should be **3**.

I can count all rows with `ongoing` project with this code snippet

```
Project::where('status', 'Ongoing')->count();
```

But cannot differentiate if a client has more than 1 projects `ongoing`. Please kindly assist me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count how many clients have at least one ongoing project you essentially have two options:

1. Group by:

```
$count = Project::where('status', 'Ongoing')
   ->select('client_id')
   ->groupBy('client_id')
   ->count();
```

2. Use an eloquent relationship

If you define a relationship between the `Client` and `Project` model you can get all clients with ongoing projects:

```
$count = Client::whereHas('project', function ($q) {
   $q->where('status', 'Ongoing');
})->count();
```

The first method should be a bit faster but if you then want to retrieve the clients it's easier to adapt the 2nd method to return the clients instead of the count

Answer (score 0):

Get the Client id for example

```
$client_id
Project::where('client_id', $clientId)->where('status', 'Ongoing')->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's returning 0 as the result.

Comment: I think that is because you are not getting the client id from request ..